# Footer stick to the bottom with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I tried to get the div.col-wrapper to stick to the bottom on firefox on high res screens using position absolute but for some reason it is messing with the jQuery slide effect. I ran out of possible solution except to in jQuery make it stick to the bottom.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").show();
    $(".list").hide();

$(".wbut").click(function(){
    $(".wbut").hide("fade");
    $(".box").hide("fade");
    $(".list").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});

$(".wbut2").click(function(){
    $(".box").show();
    $(".wbut").show();
    $(".list").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});

  });
```

css

```
.list {
background: #d1d1d1;
}

.col-wrapper {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: #d1d1d1;
box-shadow: 0px -5px 8px #777;
}
```

Comment: Tried position: static; ?

Comment: I won't click in a shortened URL. Better put the real URL and the code here :)

Comment: added the code also tried position static and the same result

Comment: I replaced your bit.ly link with the real one. Please do not continue to post your links in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

I added the position absolute to the wrong element. It should be .list not .col-wrapper